# Status pendiente al llenar un select

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, phpmyadmin

Tengo un select que al cargar el DOM se llena mediante php, sin problemas, dentro de la etiqueta select.

Luego cuando lleno el formulario tengo la opción de agregar elementos a ése select y quiero llenar de nuevo el select para que esté disponible el último elemento creado.

Después de agregar el elemento a la bd mediante el método $.ajax({}) de jquery, llamo a la función que se encarga de llenar el select pero ésta vez lo hago con el método $.post() también de jquery.

En ésta parte es que tengo el problema ya que la función para hacer la nueva carga del select "bloquea" momentáneamente el DOM porque la petición obtiene el status "pending" (por unos 5 seg. aproximadamente, a pesar de que la etiqueta network de la consola dice que fueron 51 ms) hasta que la petición obtiene el status 200 y por supuesto queda el DOM disponible.

[image: status pending]

[image: status 200]

La tabla de donde se cargan los datos tiene apenas 350 registros, la tengo con InnoDB, anteriormente por recomendaciones de compañeros la tenía en MyISAM pero el problema persistía.

Agradecería la ayuda que me puedan dar.

Comment: No debería haber ningún problema por eso. Aunque no entiendo por qué pasaste a `$post` y no lo dejaste en `$ajax`¿? El manejo de la respuesta con `$ajax` mediante `done` es mucho más claro. Inténtalo así y muestra el código que usas, por ejemplo, ¿dónde recibes la respuesta del servidor y qué haces con ella? ¿estás usando un archivo distinto para comunicar con el servidor? (imagino que sí).

Comment: Puedes poner el codigo js que hace el llenado del select? puede que el problema esté ahí.

Comment: Hola A. Cedano, gracias por responder.  

Utilizo ajax cuando necesito enviar datos para hacer un INPUT o un UPDATE y post cuando sólo quiero traer datos y mostrarlos, al menos eso es lo que se recomienda.

Comment: Ya utilicé el método ajax en lugar de post y sigue igual, es más, ahora se tarda 100 ms en cargar en lugar de 51 ms con post

Comment: No he visto en ninguna parte que se recomiende hacer diferencias de uso entre `$ajax` y `$post` en base al criterio que mencionas. En cualquier caso, el que uses `$ajax` no tiene por qué ralentizar el código, pues `$post` y `$get` son solamente *envoltorios* de `$ajax`, o sea, que éstos terminan llamando a `$ajax` siempre. Si quieres optimizar de verdad, entonces deberías usar la última versión de jQuery, y cambiar el `success` por `done`, ya que  `success` es obsoleto. Para un proceso simple como el que muestras no debería haber diferencia notable, quizá haya un problema en el servidor.

Comment: Además, las dos llamadas son distintas, una es a `ingresa_tipo.php` y otra es a `llena_cuad.php` y ninguna de ellas corresponde al nombre de archivo que muestras en la imagen. Si una llamada a una tabla con 350 registros va lenta, puede que haya un problema con los índices de la tabla, o con la consulta que no esté optimizada, o con la conexión de red o con la memoria del servidor... Un código Ajax como el que tienes no daría ningún tipo de problema.

Comment: Gracias A. Cedano por tus respuestas, las tomaré todas en cuenta. 
Los 2 ejemplos que coloqué no tienen que ver con la tabla que me da problemas, sólo las coloqué como ejemplos de cómo y cuando utilizo los 2 métodos.